# cURL - Unkown SSL protocol error - OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, curl, ssl

I am trying to use cURL and get the following error on every https request I make. The error is always the same. HTTP requests work flawlessly. The verbose output is quite useless.

```
bash:$ curl https://google.com -vv
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fe09b803a00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fe09b803a00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.226.129...
* Connected to google.com (74.125.226.129) port 443 (#0)
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to google.com:-9805
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to google.com:-9805

bash:$ curl https://google.com -V
curl 7.30.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0) libcurl/7.30.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz

bash:$ openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 < /dev/null
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
24255:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:182:
```

The results are the same on two different networks, so it does not appear to be network-specific. Attempting to connect using `openssl s_client` fails similarly so it is not library-dependent either (curl on the Mac uses SecureTransport). The debug output of `s_client` shows that the SSL handshake proceeds normally to the point where the client sends ChangeCipherSpec and the Finished messages but does not receive ChangeCipherSpec back from the server.

I have tried running these commands on a Debian VM on my Mac, and everything there runs correctly. In addition, using curl to connect to a local OpenSSL server (`openssl s_server` with a self-signed certificate) also works correctly.

I have looked through other answers on this forum and other places on the internet, but haven't found an answer. Most people's issues involve particular servers and the configuration of SSL on these servers. Mine however is problematic anytime HTTPS is used (with any website).

It was suggested that the issue might be in the certificate store. But if I understand it correctly, if the issue was with the certificate store, it would cause certificates to be rejected by all apps. However, all my browsers (chrome, safari, firefox) negotiate SSL with no problems. There is nothing suspicious in the environment variables for GUI applications or the shell.

Can someone please suggest what I should be looking into to solve the problem? Can it be that something is not properly configured? What should I be looking for?

Comment: What does `curl -V` (capital V) say? And are you behind any proxys?

Comment: I added the curl -V output to the body of the post. I am using the network at my office, but there are no proxies set up, as far as I know. I might be wrong, of course. How do I find out?

Comment: How about `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 < /dev/null`? Does this do the whole SSL handshake?

Comment: Do you have a `.curlrc` file in your home directory? If so, see if it is causing the trouble. Also try (separately) `--tlsv1` and `--sslv3` to check if changing the SSL version helps anything.

Comment: I added the output from the openssl s_client command. The handshake, in fact, fails. And I do not have a .curlc file in my home directory. And changing the ssl version does not make any difference, whatsoever.

Comment: I have noticed something that might be odd in a packet capture session. The server (google.com) sends a TCP RST packet after the client sends a ChangeCipherSpec, this is when the client is expecting a ChangeCipherSpec from the server. Why would the server abruptly send a TCP RST packet, ending the session?

Comment: Try `curl -k -vv https://50.19.125.63:4433` when you get a chance.

Comment: It worked properly. Handshake was completed successfully.

Comment: Darn, we can't make it fail when we want it to fail. curl -k doesn't work on other sites, does it?

Comment: No, it does work with some servers and fails with others. For example, amazon.com works, whereas google.com doesn't (via https). But amazon.com also seems to work without the -k flag.